# Влияние AngularJS на SEO

Tags: seo, ajax, javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возникают ли проблемы с SEO продвижением сайтов, написанных на AngularJS? Т.е. пагубно ли воспринимает поисковик директивы ng-app и тому подобные? Также хотелось бы узнать, возникают ли проблемы с SEO продвижением сайтов, контент которых подгружается AJAX'ом? Какие есть варианты решения?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, плохо сказывается angular на SEO. Ведь контентных страниц физически нет.
Есть у яндекса и гугла рекомендации, как быть в таких случаях. Они сводятся к тому, что для поисковых роботов должны быть уже сгенерированные статические дубли всех страниц.
Есть и готовые решения, например prerender.io

Answer (score -1):

Сайт с документацией по ангуляру написан на ангуляре. И индексируется он очень даже хорошо. Следовательно, при правильной реализации проблем нет.

Можно включить html5-навигацию, либо использовать рекомендуемый гуглом `!`. В обоих случаях потребуется, чтобы сервер мог отдавать уже готовые страницы при соответствующем запросе.